# why does this code doesn't go into infinite loop?

Tags: struts, struts-1

## 1)

I'm looking at some code that is perhaps Struts1 and was wondering if someone can explain why I'm not getting an infinite loop, and instead, I'm being forwarded to a jsp page instead:

struts-config.xml:

```
<struts-config>
     <global-forwards>
        <forward name="a.t" path="/Search.do"/>
     </global-forwards>
     <action-mappings>
        <action path="/Search"
              type="path.SearchAction"
              scope="request"
              name="searchForm"
              validate="true">
        <forward name="orders" path="a.t"/>
        <forward name="success" path="a.t"/>
        <forward name="cancel" path="/Search.do"/>
        </action>
     </action-mappings>
    ...
 </struts-config>
```

I searched for a.t and found it's also referenced in this
tiles.xml.  Don't know what's the purpose of this.

```
<tiles-definitions>
   <definition name="a.t"  extends="admin.default">
     <put-attribute name="content" value="/mypath/hello.jsp"/>
   </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Abridged SearchAction.java class:

```
public class SearchAction extends Action
(
   ....
   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                             HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response) throws
   Exception 
   {
       ....
       return mapping.findForward("success");
   }
)
```

My Original thinking is that since it always returns "success", and according to the struts-config.xml

```
<forward name="success" path="a.t"/>
```

it would go to find a.t, which is defined in the global-foward

```
<struts-config>
        <global-forwards>
           <forward name="a.t" path="/Search.do"/>
        </global-forwards>
```

and
      path="/Search.do"

would in theory send me back to SearchAction.java

Since

```
 <action-mappings>
       <action path="/Search"
```

points to SearchAction.java

## 2)

I don't know why the original author decided to do:

```
    <forward name="orders" path="a.t"/>
    <forward name="success" path="a.t"/>
    <forward name="cancel" path="/Search.do"/>
```

Is there a difference between

```
  <forward name="success" path="a.t"/>
vs.
  <forward name="success" path="/Search.do"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm being forwarded to a jsp page instead:

I hope you are being forwarded to hello.jsp

> My Original thinking is that since it always returns "success", and
>   according to the struts-config.xml
>
> `<forward name="success" path="a.t"/>`
>
> it would go to find a.t, which is defined in the global-foward
>
> `<struts-config>
>           <global-forwards>
>              <forward name="a.t" path="/Search.do"/>
>           </global-forwards>`
>
> and path="/Search.do"

The `path="a.t"` will not again search for mapping with same name in `<global-forwards>`. Instead it searches for the suitable mapping in `tiles.xml` and finds the following block and redirects to `hello.jsp`

```
<tiles-definitions>
   <definition name="a.t"  extends="admin.default">
     <put-attribute name="content" value="/mypath/hello.jsp"/>
   </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

> Is there a difference between
>
> ```
>  <forward name="success" path="a.t"/>
> vs.
>   <forward name="success" path="/Search.do"/>
> ```

`<forward name="success" path="a.t"/>` will get mapped to `tiles.xml` and forward to `hello.jsp`

`<forward name="success" path="/Search.do"/>` will get mapped to `SearchAction.java`. Since you have only returned `success`, it will again go to `hello.jsp`, but the original author has done so, because in future he can add any other mapping also, for different cases say, `failure`

Action class:

`return mapping.findForward("failure");`

struts-config.xml:

`<forward name="failure" path="failure.jsp"/>`